# Adobe Sign access token invalid_request

Tags: error-handling, oauth-2.0, adobe, access-token, echosign

I'm having trouble with Adobe Sign's OAuth authentication -- every time I try to get my access token with my Client ID and redirect URI, I get this message:

```
Unable to authorize access because the client configuration is invalid: invalid_request
```

This is the request that I have been making (with the proper substitution for REDIRECT and CLIENTID):

```
https://secure.echosign.com/public/oauth? redirect_uri=REDIRECT& response_type=code& client_id=CLIENTID& scope=user_login:self+agreement_send:account
```

I am fairly new to OAuth and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please explain the issues that could result in this error message?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @coffeecode do you have the solution now?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I solved it by including the correct shard in the URL after "secure." and before ".echosign". You identify your shard by looking at the URL where you created your application.

I found this information [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/unable-to-authorize-access-because-the-client-configuration-is-invalid-invalid-request-while-running-oauth-process.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Shame that the documentation doesn't mention that

Answer (score 1):

This comment might get helpful for others who are facing issue in Adobe Sign access token **invalid_request**.

Developer Guide on Sign API: https://opensource.adobe.com/acrobat-sign/developer_guide/index.html

For the Outh process and the link to be used in user's browser:
`https://secure.na1.adobesign.com/public/oauth/v2?redirect_uri=https://www.google.co.in&response_type=code&client_id=paste_your_client_id_here&scope=user_read:account`

If any one using sandbox,
`https://secure.na1.adobesignsandbox.com//public/oauth/v2?redirect_uri=https://www.google.co.in&response_type=code&client_id=paste_your_client_id_here&scope=user_read:account`

Please ensure the correct environment identifier and shard. `https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/using/identify-account-shard.html https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/unable-to-authorize-access-because-the-client-configuration-is-invalid-invalid-request-while-running-oauth-process.html`

After pasting URL in browser and allowing the access to your API and getting code. Please use endpoint URL to get access token as below:
for developer account: https://api.na1.adobesign.com/oauth/v2/token
for sandbox account: https://api.na1.adobesignsandbox.com/oauth/v2/token

Answer (score 0):

Is OK to have spaces in that https request?

Comment: Yes @szeljic -- I get the same invalid_request error with and without spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a problems with this.

I think your URL is not correct.
I using this one

```
https://secure.na2.echosign.com/public/embeddedWidget
```

for adobe widget. 
Adobe require same url for OAuth

```
https://secure.na2.echosign.com/public/oauth
```

Check your domain, and try. You can create widget just to see your domain

Comment: I tried this and it stills results in the same error. I feel like I might have something wrong with my redirect URI - should https://google.com work? I'm trying to test the Adobe platform and do not have my own site to redirect to. I know that it has to be secure and absolute - I can't tell if this is my problem

Comment: @coffecode I setup https on local, and it's working just fine.
Https is required, I think.